The Spectral Mapping Theorem for $\mathcal{C}^N$
I am trying to prove that $\sigma(p(T)) = p(\sigma(T))$ when $X = \mathcal{C}^N.$ I can see that $\sigma(p(T)) \subset p(\sigma(T))$ because if $z$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $p(z)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A).$ However, I am having trouble showing $p(\sigma(T)) \subset \sigma(p(T)).$ Any advice?
